# Error in Sample program FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Here's the code for the sample program, It's a Hello World program.

```
package

{

import flash.display.Sprite;

import flash.events.Event;

import flash.text.TextField;

/**

* …

* @author Your Name

*/

public class Main extends Sprite

{

public function Main():void

{

if (stage) init();

else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

}

private function init(e:Event = null):void

{

removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

// entry

var greeting:TextField = new TextField();
}
greeting.text = (“Hello, World”);

greeting.x = 100;

greeting.y = 100;

addChild(greeting);

}

}
```

When I run it, I get 2 syntax errors, both on line 43 \src\Main.as(43): col: 18 Error: Syntax error. What I'm doing wrong? I googled the problem and no luck, Please Help!!! Any Help would be extremely appreciated!! The link to the tutorial is here "https://precisioncode.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/a-tutorial-in-as3-with-flashdevelop/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes around “Hello, World” are copy pasted from the web and are not the character you get when you type shift and the quote key, delete the copied ones and type them yourself.